# Escrever sobre imagem com PHP

Tags: php, html, gd

Preciso que a partir de um formulário, o usuario possa escrever seus dados, para serem impressos em uma imagem pré-definida (será uma assinatura de email)

Segue código utilizado, mas a imagem não aparece!

HTML

```
   <form method="get" action="criaImg.php">
     <label>Seu Nome</label>
     <input type="text" name="nome"/>
   </form>
```

PHP

```
 // Carregar imagem já existente no servidor
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg( "foto.png" );
/* @Parametros
 * "foto.jpg" - Caminho relativo ou absoluto da imagem a ser carregada.
 */

// Cor de saída
$cor = imagecolorallocate( $imagem, 0, 0, 0 );
/* @Parametros
 * $imagem - Imagem previamente criada Usei imagecreatefromjpeg
 * 255 - Cor vermelha ( RGB )
 * 255 - Cor verde ( RGB )
 * 255 - Cor azul ( RGB )
 * -- No caso acima é branco
 */

// Texto que será escrito na imagem
$nome = urldecode( $_GET['nome'] );
/* @Parametros
 * $_GET['nome'] - Texto que será escrito
 */

// Escrever nome
imagestring( $imagem, 2, 15, 12, $nome, $cor );
/* @Parametros
 * $imagem - Imagem previamente criada Usei imagecreatefromjpeg
 * 5 - tamanho da fonte. Valores de 1 a 5
 * 15 - Posição X do texto na imagem
 * 515 - Posição Y do texto na imagem
 * $nome - Texto que será escrito
 * $cor - Cor criada pelo imagecolorallocate
 */

// Header informando que é uma imagem PNG
header( 'Content-type: image/png' );

// eEnvia a imagem para o browser ou arquivo
imagejpeg( $imagem, NULL, 80 );
/* @Parametros
 * $imagem - Imagem previamente criada Usei imagecreatefromjpeg
 * NULL - O caminho para salvar o arquivo.
          Se não definido NULL a imagem será mostrado no browser.
 * 80 - Qualidade da compresão da imagem.
 */
```

Comment: Verificou se a imagem está sendo criada corretamente? Poste o código que mostra a imagem(saída).

Comment: Obrigada por responder Jonathan,
Bom, só estou utilizando esses dois codigos... achei que o responsável pela saida fosse esse proprio php ..

Comment: Você utiliza imagem .png e chama ela com .jpeg. Isso que está errado.